# Expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '=' token

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, avr, atmelstudio

I have little problem while programming Atmega328

This piece of code gives error:

```
expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '=' token
```

in Atmel Studio 7

```
struct
{
    const uint8_t fioletowy[3] = {255,0,255};
    const uint8_t blekitny[3] = {0,255,255};
    const uint8_t czerwony[3] = {255,0,0};
    const uint8_t zielony[3] = {0,255,0};
    const uint8_t niebieski[3] = {0,0,255};
    const uint8_t pomaranczowy[3] = {255,128,0};
    const uint8_t zolty[3] = {255,255,0};
    const uint8_t bialy[3] = {255,255,255};
    const uint8_t rozowy[3] = {255,100,255};
    const uint8_t cyjanowy[3] = {0,255,225};
} kolory;
```

Whole code [here](http://pastebin.com/K4WhWX3L)

Comment: You should try reading some of the answers here: [Why can't we initialize members inside a structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225089/why-cant-we-initialize-members-inside-a-structure)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize members of a `struct` using that syntax. You can use:

```
struct
{
   const uint8_t fioletowy[3];
   const uint8_t blekitny[3];
   ...
} kolory = 
{
   {255,0,255},
   {0,255,255},
   ...
};
```