# Initialize array inside struct in C in Visual Studio

Tags: c, arrays, struct, visual-studio-2015

In this struct I want to initialize an array but Visual Studio marks an error right after `rulesRefIndex[3]`

> expected a ';'

```
struct Fact{
    char name[4];
    char value[6];
    int rulesRefIndex[3] = { -1 };
};
```

Error occurs even with `int rulesRefIndex[3] = { -1,-1,-1 };` and `int rulesRefIndex[3] = {[0...3]= -1 };` as stated [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize only when defining a variable, not when defining a structure(datatype) in c. Check the following post for details.

[Why can't we initialize members inside a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225089/why-cant-we-initialize-members-inside-a-structure)

Moreover your question is related to partial initialization. Please check this post.

[C and C++ : Partial initialization of automatic structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828294/c-and-c-partial-initialization-of-automatic-structure)

Comment: Thanks, so how can I assign values to such array? Regular assignment will do?

Comment: @Mike You can assign values to the array when you create the array (with `malloc`, or on the stack, or however)

Comment: @immibis but how it will be in this case, when my array is defined in struct?

Comment: @Mike Well how would you initialize `name` and `value`?